# Proof that the Identity Relation is a subset of a Relation composed with its Inverse

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

I found this problem in my professor's set theory notes:

$"$Let $R \subseteq A \times A$.  Prove

$$I_{A} \subseteq R \circ R^{-1} \quad \text{ and } \quad I_{A} \subseteq R^{-1} \circ R."$$

First off, while I did attempt a solution (shown below), this problem doesn't even sound right.  If anything I would think $R \circ R^{-1}, R^{-1} \circ R \subseteq I_{A}$. By definition
$$I_{A}=\{ (a,a) \in A \times A | a \in A\},$$
ergo it seems to be capable of containing many elements not found in $R \circ R^{-1}, R^{-1} \circ R$. Anyways, here is my attempt at a solution:

---

Take $(x,x),(y,y) \in I_{A}$ such that $xRy$.  Note $xRy$ implies $yR^{-1}x$. Note also that $xRy$ and $yR^{-1}x$ imply
$$(x,x) \in R^{-1} \circ R$$
and
$$(y,y) \in R \circ R^{-1} \text{.}$$
Hence, if $(x,x),(y,y) \in I_{A}$, then $(x,x) \in R^{-1} \circ R$ and $(y,y) \in R \circ R^{-1}$. Thus $I_{A} \subseteq R^{-1} \circ R, R \circ R^{-1}$.

---

Anyways, he's got the phD and I don't so I'm probably wrong somewhere in my thinking.  Any help would be appreciated guys, thank you!

Comment: Is there any additional condition on what type of relations $R$ is allowed to be?  For example, must $R$ be an equivalence relation?  If not... then let $A\neq \emptyset$ and let $R = \emptyset$...

Comment: Thank you for the response, and no.  This problem comes from a very early section only covering the basics of relations.  It doesn't even cover equivalence relations or  orderings yet.

Comment: As for disproving $R\circ R^{-1}\subseteq I_A$, consider $|A|>1$ and $R = A\times A$, the trivial equivalence relation where everything is related to everything.  You would have here $R\circ R^{-1} = A\times A$ is a strict superset of $I_A$ and so is not a subset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither inclusion holds in general: for instance, if $A=\{1,2\}$ and $R=\{(1,1)\}$, then $R^{-1}\circ R = R\circ R^{-1} = \{(1,1)\} = R$, but it neither composition contains  $I_A$.

Now, what *is* true is the following: let $R$ be a relation on $A$, and let the domain and codomain of $R$ be given by:
$$\begin{align*}
D=\mathrm{dom}(R) &= \{a\in A\mid \exists b\in A\text{ such that }(a,b)\in R\}\\
\text{and }E=\mathrm{codom}(R) &= \{a\in A\mid \exists c\in A\text {such that }(c,a)\in R\}.
\end{align*}$$
Then $I_D\subseteq R^{-1}\circ R$ and $I_E\subseteq R\circ R^{-1}$

Indeed: let $d\in D$; then there exists $b\in A$ such that $(d,b)\in R$, and hence $(b,d)\in R^{-1}$. Therefore, $(d,d)\in R^{-1}\circ R$. Thus, $I_D\subseteq R^{-1}\circ R$.

And let $e\in E$. Then there exists $a\in A$ such that $(a,e)\in R$. Hence $(e,a)\in R^{-1}$, $(a,e)\in R$, hence $(e,e)\in R\circ R^{-1}$. Thus, $I_E\subseteq R\circ R^{-1}$. (Alternatively, $\mathrm{dom}(R)=\mathrm{codom}(R^{-1})$ and $\mathrm{codom}(R)=\mathrm{dom}(R^{-1})$, so the second inclusion follows from the first by swapping the roles of $R$ and $R^{-1}$.

In fact, this is the best that can be said in this direction: suppose $R\subseteq A\times A$ is a relation, and $a\in A\setminus \mathrm{dom}(R)$. I claim that $(a,a)\notin R^{-1}\circ R$; that is, if $I_X\subseteq R^{-1}\circ R$, then $X\subseteq D$:

Indeed, suppose that $(a,a)\in R^{-1}\circ R$; then there exists $b\in A$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,a)\in R^{-1}$. But then $a\in D$. Thus, if $I_{X}\subseteq R^{-1}\circ R$, then $X\subseteq D$. The domain of $R$ is the largest subset of $A$ whose identity relation is contained in $R^{-1}\circ R$.

Symmetrically, $E$ is the largest subset of $A$ whose identity relation is contained in $R^{-1}\circ R$.

---

Your argument is correct as far as it goes up to the "Thus $I_A\subseteq R^{-1}\circ R$, $R\circ R^{-1}$", because you did not show that *every* element of $I_A$ lies in $R^{-1}\circ R$, you only showed that an element of $I_A$ *that satisfies some extra conditions* (namely, its first entry being $R$-related to someone) lies in $R^{-1}\circ R$. To reach your conclusion, you would need to either show that *every* element of $I_A$ satisfies this extra condition, or else deal with the case in which the element of $I_A$ does *not* satisfy the condition.

Finally, on your "if anything. $R^{-1}\circ R\subseteq I_A$"... I'm not sure why that would be; imagine that $R$ is *everything*: $R=A\times A$, so that $R^{-1}=A\times A$. Then the composition is again everything, and not merely *some* pairs with identical first and last entry. Perhaps you are thinking of functions, where $f^{-1}\circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$. But if so, you should think that with relations you should get *at least* as much as you get with functions, but often more (because the same element of $A$ may be $R$-related to *many* elements in a relation, whereas only to one element in a function). So you may guess that you get *at least* $I_A$, but not that you get *at most* $I_A$.

Comment: Very helpful, and thank you.  This sheds a lot of light on the topic.

Comment: "*... and $R=\{(1,1)\}$ ... but it neither contains (nor is contained in) $I_A$*"  But $\{(1,1)\}$ is in fact a subset of $\{(1,1),(2,2)\}=I_A$.  This is not a counterexample to $R\circ R^{-1}\subseteq I_A$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: True; thank you.

Comment: More simply, let $R=\varnothing$ then, as long as $A\neq\varnothing$, it's immediately obvious that $I_A$ won't be contained in either.