# Prove by induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (I_A \subseteq R^n \circ R^{-n})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, induction

Let $R$ be a binary relation and $A = Dom(R) \cup Ran(R)$. Prove by
induction that $I_A \subseteq R^n \circ R^{-n}$ for every natural $n$.

I reached the conclusion in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344307/proof-that-the-identity-relation-is-a-subset-of-a-relation-composed-with-its-inv), but I think my problem asks for a generalization of what is found there. The book from where I took the problem gives the hint: *use the fact that for any relations $R_1$, $R_2$, $S_1$, and $S_2$, if $R_1 \subseteq R_2$ and $S_1 \subseteq S_2$, then $R_1 \circ S_1 \subseteq R_2 \circ S_2$*.

**Basis.** Let $n = 1$ and $(x,x) \in I_A$. Then either $x \in Dom(R)$ or $x \in Ran(R)$. If $x \in Dom(R)$, there is some $y$ such that $(x,y) \in R$, which implies that $(y,x) \in R^{-1}$. Hence, $(x,x) \in R^{-1} \circ R \therefore I_A \subseteq R^{-1} \circ R$. Likewise, if $x \in Ran(R)$, there is some $y$ such that $(y,x) \in R$, which implies that $(x,y) \in R^{-1}$. Hence, $(x,x) \in R \circ R^{-1} \therefore I_A \subseteq R\circ R^{-1} $.

**Step.** Let $k \geq 1$. Suppose $I_A \subseteq R^k \circ R^{-k}$. To prove $I_A \subseteq R^{k+1} \circ R^{-(k+1)}$, notice that $$R^{k+1} \circ R^{-(k+1)} = (R^k \circ R) \circ (R^{-k} \circ R^{-1}).$$ I haven't thought much further because the base case is bothering me. When $x \in Ran(R)$, the claim was proved. However, since composition is not commutative, when $x \in Dom(R)$ the conclusion was not reached, and I think that is not even possible. As for the inductive step, am I headed towards the right direction? I didn't see how to use the hint yet.

Comment: Istn't $R^{-n}=(R^n)^{-1}$ anyway?

Comment: I think it is. I don't see how is that helpful, sorry if it's obvious. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As William Elliot said, the problem is incorrect as stated.  What your argument in "Basis" goes to show is not $I_A \subseteq R \circ R^{-1}$, $I_A \subseteq R^{-1} \circ R$, but $I_Y \subseteq R \circ R^{-1}$, $I_X \subseteq R^{-1} \circ R$, where $X$ is the domain of $R$ and $Y$ its range.

To prove inductively that $I_Y \subseteq R^n \circ R^{-n}$, for the inductive step, begin with
\begin{align}
  R^{k + 1} \circ R^{-(k + 1)} &= \left(R^k \circ R\right) \circ \left(R^{-1} \circ R^{-k}\right)\\
 &= R^k \circ \left(R \circ R^{-1}\right) \circ R^{-k}.
\end{align}

[edited to add:]

Some of the things that William Elliot said don't agree with the definition of composition of relations that I'm familiar with, and that I think you're working with; but even with that definition it's true, and along the same general lines as his remarks, that to prove the result for general $n$ you need some further assumption, and that a sufficient condition is that the domain and range of $R$ are equal.

Comment: Thanks for summarizing everything. Your inductive step raised me a doubt. The definition of negative power relation I saw states that $R^{-(k+1)}=R^{-k} \circ R^{-1}$. Is this the same as $R^{-1} \circ R^{-k}$ because $R^{-k}=(R^{-1})^{k}$ (so no problem in commuting)? Just wanted to make sure! xD

Comment: @Lucas Peres: That $R^{-k} \circ R^{-1} = R^{-1} \circ R^{-k}$ follows from the fact that composition of relations is associative.  Proving it rigorously, though, involves another induction.